# How can I create a checkbox filter on c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, checkbox, filter

I'm having a problem that seems way more easy than it is. I think its more of an algorithmic problem than a coding one.

EDIT:
Imagine you have a database with a name and N boolean parameters, like if the person is blonde or not, if the person likes baseball or not, if person have a smartphone or not etc...

How could you print the name of someone that likes baseball AND is blonde, but doesn't matter if any of the other N parameters are true of false? How can I do that without having to write a test for every single of the (N^2)-1 possibilities?

<s>I created a dictionary that maps a string to a struct with 4 boolean variables and some strings.</s>

I want the user to select which booleans are important to them and return only the information that is true for all variable that he chose. 
Something like a checkbox which you can use to filter a column in excel.

For instance if a user chose variables 1 and 2, I would like to know if there is a better way to return the result rather than testing every one of the 16 possibilities, like:

```
void filter(map<string, Mystruct> Mydictionary, bool bool1, bool bool2, bool bool3, bool bool4){
   if(bool1 == true && bool2 == true && bool3 == false && bool4==false){
     cout << Mydictionary.bool1Info << Mydictionary.bool2Info
   if(bool1 == true && bool2 == false && bool3 == false && bool4==false)
   ...
```

Even more, for me its only important to test the booleans that the user picked up, so even if he didn't choose boolean3, it's not important to test if its true or false.

Any ideas?

I would be very glad if anyone could help me with this one

Comment: probably not a great title... I really didn't know how to summarize my problem : /

Comment: `Mydictionary.bool1Info` certainly isn't valid code if `Mydictionary` is of type `map<string, Mystruct>`. So, is your problem how the language works? How to use maps? Those are pretty well covered on thousands of sites and texts.

Comment: store all bools as one number, so if he mark first bool it can be 8 if second it can be 4, if third than 2, if combine first and third it will be 10 ;) This can be easy to return and decode.

Comment: @WhozCraig I supose you are right, but that is not the problem I'm trying to address. My problem is, imagine you have a data base, and you want to print the names of everyone that like soccer AND are blonde, but don't want to print the names of everyone that like soccer OR are blonde. How could you do that for N parameters without testing every single one, and you don't know which parameters the user would want to select?

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with your algorithm part , 
instead of checking all 16 possibilities just check 4 conditions separately for bool1,2,3,4 and print their info if they are true.

This way you can complete your task with only 4 if statements.

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: Hello Uddhav, thank you for your help, but I think this would not solve my problem. This would print the info 1 if bool1 is 1, info 2 if bool 2 is true, like an OR statment, but I need a AND. I need info1 and info 2 to be printed only if bool 1 and bool 2 are true. Like if you try to filter the name of everyone that are blonde and likes soccer. But not the names of everyone that happens to be blonde or happens to like soccer. Hope I could explain my problem better now